# Combustion of carbon with hydrogen

Tags: energy

Can coal (carbon) be "burned" in a hydrogen atmosphere? I know it would not match the definition of "combustion".

But is the reaction $$\ce{C +2H2 ->CH4}$$ exothermic?

(I'm fairly convinced this is a duplicate, but I didn't find any question like that.)

Comment: To find the enthalpy change associated with the reaction you can find heats of formation and use Hess' law. The heats of formation you need can probably be easily found online or in a textbook.

Comment: @orthocresol Thank you, but I need some more help. I have no textbook, I'm out of school for some decades. A link would be useful.

Comment: Google is your friend! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane_(data_page)

Comment: Please mention the state of reactants so that there is no confusion while calculating the enthalpy change. I suppose that you asked it out of curiosity, in that case yes it is exothermic.

Comment: @PRITIPRIYADASBEHERA I did not know that curiosity contributed to making a reaction exothermic...

Comment: Yes, I have seen that I was thinking too complex, I didn't expect an easy solution, but just adding up entropy enough. Will promptly delete that silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formation reaction of CH4 is exothermic. The heat of formation is : -75 kJ/mol

Comment: In my opinion, citing a reputable source for the data would make it a better answer. Also, probably a brief note on terminology (something along the lines why "*combustion*" isn't the best term here) wouldn't hurt either, I think.